# I'm trying to access Excel file to export it to SQL database with ASP.NET and VB.NET but getting following error

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, excel

> **The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need
>   permission to view and write its data.**

I'm trying to Import Excel file from ASP.NET and VB.NET to update it to my SQL server. But i'm getting the following error. Please give me a solution. 
VB.NET Code.

```
Dim strConnection As [String] = "projectlist"
    Dim path As String = fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName
    Dim excelConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & path & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False;Mode= Share Deny None;Persist Security Info=False;Mode=12"
    Dim excelConnection As New OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select [ID],[Name],[Designation] from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection)
    excelConnection.Open()
    Dim dReader As OleDbDataReader
    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim sqlBulk As New SqlBulkCopy(strConnection)
    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Excel_table"
    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader)
    excelConnection.Close()
```

Web.config Code

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="projectlist" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\PT-33\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\LT_V1\Data\projects_list.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Tried setting permissions to the folder i.e. NETWORK SERVICE permission but its not working.

This was my Initial Excel Connection String

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have closed the excel file. Go to your task manager. Check is there any **Microsoft Office excel** app or background process is running. If yes, select that and click on `End task` button.

Answer (score 0):

As it says, maybe that file is already open by some program (you). As a workaround you can copy file to temporary location and open it from there

You may not saved file. Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in section **Saving Uploaded Files**

Comment: Hm. Try using this connection string  "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"; where {0} is path to file and verify if posted file was actually saved to disk and if your path variable is correct